# external network routing to iis full not iis express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have configured IIS express to work on port 80 and 443 and set up a certificate and add bindings to the configuration file.

All is working fine and as expected on my development machine.

I can access `http://pete-laptop/` and `https://pete-laptop` and all is good.

I want to access this from my iPhone and iPad too to check how it displays et c.

I've tried logging in with `http://pete-laptop/` and `https://pete-laptop` and no joy.

I've tried `http://pete-laptop.local` and also my IP address. both of these options display the IIS (full) holding page (bluey greeny IIS7 logo) as it seems to be routing it to the full version of IIS rather than express.

How do I get it to route incoming traffic on pete-laptop to IIS express rather than IIS full?

I have done the following, is that not enough?

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://pete-laptop:80/ user=everyone
netsh http add urlacl url=https://pete-laptop:443/ user=everyone
```

Comment: Do you have IIS and IIS-express both running simultaneously? If so, can you check the bindings on IIS? By default IIS binds to port 80.

Comment: i do have iis installed and starts up with windows. how do i remove the bindings to port 80 and 443 from iis full? i know where the config file is for express but not iis full. and what do i need to change?

Comment: Start->run->inetmgr - On the 'Default Web Site' there should be an option to 'Edit Bindings'. This will show all the bindings that get routed to IIS.

Comment: Bindings set as: http:*:80:,net.tcp:808:*,net.pipe:*,net.msmq:localhost,msmq.formatname:localhost    how do i change this as its a read only field?

Comment: iv changed that to a different port number. the iphone is getting a 404 now, it's still not routing to iis express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be multiple things working against you:

[Edit IIS binding](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding)

Next, try to set IIS-express to :. Some pointers [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/rfennell/archive/2011/03/22/how-to-expose-iis-express-to-external-network-connections-and-use-a-non-self-signed-certificate.aspx)

Comment: Iv got it working. after i used your advice and changed the iis(full) binding away from port 80, i just needed to add:

<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:pete-laptop.local"/>
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:pete-laptop.local" />

This then lets me access the site from my iphone using the pete-laptop.local

Thanks for your help with this, i have been going round in circles.

Comment: Glad this helped. Please mark this as an answer if it is relevant.